# Game network programming synchronizing graphs

Tags: network-programming, game-engine

I am trying to develop a computer game. I want this game to be multiplayer playable. The game is an arcade space shooter

I plan to run the game at server level and then send updates at the clients. The problem that I am facing is object creation. Let's say if a player shots, the shots themselves are new objects. These will need to be created.

In my game I have a hierarchical structure and the shots themselves will be part of this structure. It will be something like a tree. The problem that I have is identifying objects on the clients and server.

How can I make sure that when the client receives some update then it will update the right objects?

What about new object creation. In my case the scene graph is traversed and each object is updated once it gets updates from the server. But updates which creates new object violates this principle. How should I handle them?

Also, I can't really get updates for the entire scene. I would only need to update specific objects that are visible to the player. What should I do with the rest of the objects that aren't visible? What will happen when they become visible? How can I track when objects become visible to a player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make sure that when the client receives some update then it
>   will update the right objects?

You can give an unique `id` to each object server creates. You might want to create a super `Object` class containing `id` and let all other game object classes inherit from it. Or, you can have a map to link between `id` and `object`. Or, you can mix them. To get an unique id,  server can have a global 'nextID' as int and simply assign to a new object and increase it for next one.

> But updates which creates new object violates this principle.

I don't really understand the principle you are talking about but if you are worried about editing your scene graph (or game object list) while traversing it, you can put the newly created objects into another list and just insert the new ones after traversing is done. They will start getting updated from next update. (You should consider how you will remove an object too)

> What should I do with the rest of the objects that aren't visible?
>   What will happen when they become visible?

Well, you are the one who should figure it out because it really depends on your game system. My suggestion is that try to skip their updates and see what problems appear and fix them.

> How can I track when objects become visible to a player?

Also, several ways to handle this. Server can detect everything for clients and send only visible object info for each client. Or, each client can detect them and send a request to server for starting to update visible ones. Or, it could be mixed way.

Try server-driven one first and see if server can perform it with maximum number of clients.To use client-driven one, remember each client still needs to update all object location regardless of their visibility but send a request for AI updates for only visible ones.

Again, there are many ways to handle this kind of problems and it really depends on your game system requirements. That's why it's hard to answer your question without knowing your game system well enough. Try to investigate how other similar multiplayer games are designed from some books or google. Good luck!